# Delayed BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to disable interactions with BottomNavigationBar for period of time after element of it was tapped.
I've tried to do that with AbsorbPointer:

```
int _bottomBarIndex = 0;
  bool _isPageTwo = false;
Widget callPage(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
          _isPageTwo = false;
        return Page1();
      case 1:
          _isPageTwo = true;
        return Page2();
      case 2:
          _isPageTwo = false;
        return Page3();
      default:
          _isPageTwo = false;
        return Page1();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: _isPageTwo,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _bottomBarIndex,
          // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
          onTap: (value) {
            _bottomBarIndex = value;
            setState(() {

            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text(
                  '',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0.0),
                )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
                title: Text(
                  '',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0.0),
                )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
                title: Text(
                  '',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0.0),
                ))
          ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: callPage(_bottomBarIndex),
    );
  }
```

But it always lock interactions one page too late and I would also need to somehow use timer, which means I would need to send pages to body asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the both solution. After `3000ms` the `BottomNavigationBar` will be activated again, you can change the time according to your needs.

```
int _bottomBarIndex = 0, _activateTime = 3000;
bool _isPageTwo = false;

Widget callPage(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return Page1();
    case 1:
      return Page2();
    case 2:
      return Page3();
    default:
      return Page1();
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: _isPageTwo,
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _bottomBarIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          _bottomBarIndex = value;
          switch (value) {
            case 0:
              _isPageTwo = false;
              break;
            case 1:
              // locking it here as soon as user taps this option
              _isPageTwo = true;
              break;
            case 2:
              _isPageTwo = false;
              break;

            default:
              _isPageTwo = false;
          }
          setState(() {});

          // unlocking it here after 3000 ms
          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: _activateTime), (){
            setState(() {
              _isPageTwo = false;
            });
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0.0),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
            title: Text(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0.0),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.event_note),
            title: Text(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: callPage(_bottomBarIndex),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even think about something like this